# tmux - How to start executable initially?

Tags: debian, tmux

With GNU screen I could do, for example:

```
screen -S monitor top
```

A screen would start executing top, and if top ended the screen session would end.

Is there a way to do the same thing with tmux?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start tmux and make it execute a particular command. However unlike screen, a Tmux window does not end when the command exits. I assume that in screen, the executing command and the screen window are in the same process and hence they both get killed together.

> tmux new-session -s test top

-s specifies the name of the session (test in this case)

Comment: `tmux` exits when I quit `top` here, version 1.6.

Comment: @Thor For me `tmux` quits when I exit `top` as long as it's the only window in the session, which is perfect. Thanks guys.

Comment: If you are already connected to a `tmux` session, you can also start a new window (`tmux new-window top`) or a new pane (`tmux split-window top`).